# Read space separated values

Tags: java, file-io, io

I am trying to read space separated value from a configuration file. I am reading a PostgreSQL configuration file `pg_hba.conf` file, where below is the data the file has:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:

host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
```

I have to get the above values host, all, all, 127.0.0.1/32, md5 and modify and write the modified values back to the same file.

Below is the code I use to read the file:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pg_hba.conf"));
String str;
str = in.readLine();
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
in.close();
```

How can I get the those space separated values? 
Is it possible to write it again with the same format i.e. with same amount of space back to this file?

Can we use the `Property` class for this?

Comment: Just a hint: You could solve that problem with regular expressions. Parse the whole line you read, build groups. Take a look at the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. Also search for java regular expressions on stackoverflow, there are a lot of examples how to use them.

Comment: @anonymous : Good solution for this would be use regex for spotting spaces and tab from the line ,ur options can be pattern , scanner etc..

Answer (score 3):

You can use for example the method [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) from the standard Java class [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

```
str.split("\\s+");
```

Another possibility is to use a more "advanced" library like [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), that offers good utility classes such as [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) for such tasks:

```
Splitter.on(' ').split("foo bar")
```

Comment: if I use str.split(" ") , where my stringa are separated by more than one space , so I need to iterate  over the string array returned by split and find the strings which are not blank and retrieve it ?

Comment: just use `str.split("\\s+");` (and look at the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class)

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.split() method.

```
   String[] sa= str.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a csv reading framework with custom separators. You'll be much quicker that way and have less code to maintain.

[Open CSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#custom-sepators) looks most mature, but  you should watch [apache commons csv](http://commons.apache.org/csv/) too.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume that the format of input string won't change. Based on that the code fragments are provided.

> How can I get the those space separated values ?

```
String values[] = new String[9];
bool addingSpace = false;
String value = "";
int ind = 0;
for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
{
    char indexValue = str.charAt(i);
    if(Character.isWhitespace(indexValue))
    {
        if(!addingSpace)
        {
            values[ind++] = value;
            value = "";
        }
        addingSpace = true;
    } 
    else if(Character.isLetter(indexValue))
    {
        if(addingSpace)
        {
            values[ind++] = value;
            value = "";
        }
        addingSpace = false;
    }

    value += indexValue;
}
```

> Is it possible to write it again with the same format i.e. with same amount of space back to this file ?

```
String values[] = new String[9];
```

This array has all the data with the exact no. of spaces in between. When you want to write down to file, you can use same array.